# Multiple known types ArrayOfstring on IService methods

Tags: azure-service-fabric, known-types

Late converting our fabric services from V1 to V2 and running into problems with known types.  Using 3.4.677 of Remoting.

Getting the following error:

````
```Type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]' cannot be added to list of known types since another type 'System.String[]' with the same data contract name 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays:ArrayOfstring' is already present.```
````

No of the objects (i.e. contracts) returned by service methods (i.e. `IService`) use anything other than `string[]` as a collection of string.  The problem arises in the `IService` method definitions in particular on parameter (note: not return types).  Changing all `List<string>` to `string[]` in a method parameters solves the problem.  However, I would like to not alter the `IService` interface.

The error states that an additional "known type" of `ArrayOfstring` can not be added.  The addition of [ServiceKnownType(typeof(List))](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.serviceknowntypeattribute?view=netframework-4.8) attribute on methods with `List<string>` has no effect.

Is there any other attribute that can be applied to effect the produced xml definition to allow additional `ArrayOfstring` types?

Comment: can you try using a `KnownType` attribute on your data contract instead?

Comment: The problem isn't on the model side rather the service that exposes the underlying model in particular the method parameters that use List<string>.  Haven't found any other attributes that allow for multiple known types of ArrayOfstring.